# constraint violation civicrm_subscription_history on Member Join

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

CiviCRM 4.7.14, 
Joomla 3.6.5, 
CiviGroupSync 2.1.0

It seems the contact_id is not being passed in causing the constraint violation.

```
[callback] => Array
    (
        [0] => CRM_Core_Error
        [1] => exceptionHandler
    )

[code] => -3
[message] => DB Error: constraint violation
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_subscription_history (group_id , date , method , status ) VALUES ( 73 ,  20170202135245 , 'API' , 'Removed' )  [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wifs_j15`.`civicrm_subscription_history`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_subscription_history_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_subscription_history (group_id , date , method , status ) VALUES ( 73 ,  20170202135245 , 'API' , 'Removed' )  [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wifs_j15`.`civicrm_subscription_history`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_subscription_history_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: constraint violation" code=-3 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="INSERT INTO civicrm_subscription_history (group_id , date , method , status ) VALUES ( 73 ,  20170202135245 , 'API' , 'Removed' )  [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wifs_j15`.`civicrm_subscription_history`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_subscription_history_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]"]
```

In the backtrace, the contact_id exists prior to this, so why is it not being passed? I believe this fatal error is causing the Contribution to remain in pending status.

This happened when a member provided a contribution while registering for a membership.

Comment: Thanks for your post.  It would be helpful if you could edit the question to include the steps you took that resulted in this error.